# Teaching GIS Project Workflow?

Tags: analysis, workflow

If you had to teach someone the key stages to a typical GIS Analysis project, what would be the best generic answer?

I would like to see diagrams to illustrate this point.
Do not think it requires a long-winded answer.

I have been looking at [Esri's answer.](http://gis.com/content/answering-questions-gis)

This is the best I have found so far, but was wondering if **we** (community wiki) could do better.  I am thinking, perhaps a nice workflow diagram would be good.

Comment: How do I convert to c-wiki?

Comment: It will help for respondents to **indicate what constitutes their "typical" project** and **what they mean by "analysis."** Most workflows will be appropriate only for certain interpretations and inappropriate for others.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of searching for a "typical" GIS workflow, we're better off looking for ways that GIS can fit into enterprise workflows. GIS Analysts often have a reputation for building their own information silos.  We need to focus on ways we can package our analysis so that it plugs into an enterprise workflow.

Take [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx) (WF), for example.  As far as I know, [Geocortex Essentials](http://resources.geocortex.com/essentials/apis/) is the only GIS package that [leverages WF](http://resources.geocortex.com/essentials/apis/rest/Concepts/Build/Default/WorkingWithGEAbout_Workflow.html).  Essentials exposes [workflows as REST endpoints](http://sampleserver1.geocortex.com/geocortex/essentials/Rest/sites/CharlotteArcGISOnline/workflows).  Like Silverlight/WPF, WF uses XAML which makes it easier to [build designers.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb153576%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)   Part of the Geocortex Workflow is the visual designer, that allows you to simplify the process of connecting events and directing the actual workflow.  You can see a screenshot on this [Geocortex Blog post from August 2010](http://blog.geocortex.com/2010/07/25/geocortex-essentials-3-0-released/).  The designer embeds the WF designer, and so it looks similar to this:

[image]

David Chappell has a good discussion of WF [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd851337.aspx).
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

GIS Workflow in ArcGIS in simple terms

Workflow Manager schema now replaces the JTX (Job Tracking) 3.0.1 Database

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it is what you are looking for (not exactly diagrams) but one of the best examples of GIS spatial analysis workflow I have seen is presented in this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMaMmaTfsQE

a bit fast, but shows how several transforms progressively reveal information from data. Other videos of the author may be relevant too.

Answer (score 0):

I like the ESRI answer but would add some points.

1. You cannot assume that the data is in a form that can answer your questions in a simple way.  Often the difficulty is converting a large dataset in to a form in which a geoprocessing tool or spatial SQL can work with.  This is where GDAL, OGR, FME, Python and other such tools are so essential.
2. As a final stage it is essential to check your results using a different process.  Outputs always need to be tested.  This can be simply measuring with the ruler.